# BigInteger to Hexadecimal colon notation

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using java.security.cert.X509Certificate to fetch an SSL certificate via the SSL socket. But X509Certificate returns the serial number of the certificate as a BigInteger object. What I want is the serial number in the format of the colon separated value (similar to what we see when we view the certificate details from the browser). How do we do this?

I tried toString(16), but am still left without the colon in my serial number.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert colons after each group of two digits with a simple regex, like this:

```
String res = orig.replaceAll("(?<=..)(..)", ":$1")
```

This expression matches groups of two characters, and inserts a colon in front of each group except the first one.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/PpZza4).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this approach and it seems to work fine, but i have a small issue. My BigInteger.toString() returns me a value of 17796998956082362239, which as per the code serialNo.toString(16).toUpperCase().replaceAll("(?<=..)(..)", ":$1") returns F6:FB:A4:42:0D:49:77:7F, but the brower version of the certificate has a 00 in front. i.e. 00:F6:FB:A4:42:0D:49:77:7F . IS this ok to have

Comment: @AkhilAchuthan It depends on the use that you have for your string. Your result has 64 bits, theirs - 72 bits with 8 leading zeros. You can always add `"00:"` prefix to your number if you must match their result.